# changing datasource of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I try a much too Long time to solve that problem:

I use a window with 4 "cascading" datagrids. Means, when changing the selected item of first datagrid all "following" datagrids change their complete content.

Therefore I use something like

```
ObservableCollection<LocalShape> shapeList = new ObservableCollection<LocalShape>();
```

as datasource, where

```
    struct LocalShape
    {
        public string shapeName { set; get; }
        public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource shapePicture { set; get; }
    };
```

is an example of my collection.

To change the content I try to use shapeList.Clear() and get an error, don't understand why.

Comment: Can you provide details of the error?

Comment: in english it would be something like "index out of range"

Comment: That suggests that maybe you need to set your selected item to null before clearing the collection

Comment: datagridShape.SelectedIndex = -1;
            shapeList.Clear();

gives me an error already when the first line is reached

Comment: kidshaw, you helped me to solve the problem! You gave me the right hint, but I did not recognice that I run into the SelectionChanged event where I do something with the selectedItem (which is null now). It works now, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, I have explained it in more detail as an answer. If you think it merits it, please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you're bound to a collection and a selected item, the value for selected item must be in your collection.

If you change your collection and the selected item is no longer part of it, when he control tries to update to the new collection it is looking for the selected item to stand out. If it doesn't find it you get an exception.

It is the changing of the collection that causes this knock on exception. Before changing the collection, first test the selected item exists in the new collection and if it does not, set the selected item to null.